# Spring WebClient Error - reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly cannot be cast to class reactor.core.publisher.Mono

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spring-webflux

Following is the rest service that I have implemented

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE, value = "/events")
Flux<Event> events() {
    Flux<Event> eventFlux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate {new Event(System.currentTimeMillis(), LocalDate.now())})
    Flux<Long> durationFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    return Flux.zip(eventFlux, durationFlux)
    .map {it.t1}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ReactiveServiceApplication)
}
```

The webclient to consume this looks as follows.

```
 @Bean
    WebClient client() {
        return WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080")
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner demo (WebClient client) {
        return { args ->
            client.get().uri("/events")
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap { response -> response.bodyToFlux(Event.class) }
            .subscribe { println it }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ReactiveClientApplication)
            .properties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port","8081"))
            .run(args)
    }
```

The error I am getting is as follows.

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.ClassCastException: class reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly cannot be cast to class reactor.core.publisher.Mono (reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly and reactor.core.publisher.Mono are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly cannot be cast to class reactor.core.publisher.Mono (reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly and reactor.core.publisher.Mono are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.3.5.RELEASE.jar:3.3.5.RELEASE]
```

Why is the error happening ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that using `flatMap` actualy returns a `Mono`. So the closure `{ response -> response.bodyToFlux(Event.class) }` was actually returning a `Flux` where as the `flatMap` was expecting a `Mono`.

Changing to `flatMapMany` will fix this. Code below.

```
    CommandLineRunner getFluxDemoExchange (WebClient client) {
        return { args ->
            client.get().uri("/events")
                    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                    .exchange()
                    .flatMapMany { response -> response.bodyToFlux(Event.class) }
                    .subscribe { println it }
        }
    }
```